Android studio. Привязка элемента к toolbar
Есть кастомный toolbar, в каждом фрагменте для верхнего элемента приходится прописывать отступ от верхнего крана экрана, чтобы элемент не уезжал под этот самый toolbar. А есть ли возможность прописать привязку к самому toolbar, по типу Top to Bottom?

Toolbar находится в Activty? Для того, чтобы вам можно было помочь, приведите разметку Activity и одного из фрагментов.
